# Controllers and Views inside a Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a group of controllers and Views that I use in many projects. I was wondering if I could place then inside a class library and reuse it as a normal lib file.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely doable. Things you'll need:

1. Some way of registering the routes on app start.
2. A view engine that knows about both the library views and your application specific views.

The first is easy. Just write a function in your library that registers all the controllers in the library.

The second is more complicated, but you can read some good articles on writing your own view engine, [here](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/30/partitioning-an-aspnet-mvc-application-into-separate-areas/) and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx). The concept of Areas may be useful too for separating your library controllers from your app controllers.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc) addresses the simplest case of finding views in an arbitrary folder.

Answer (score 1):

The controllers can just go into a class library - not much to do there.  The views are a bit more difficult.  You should be able to embed them in the assembly and implement a [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) to provide access to them.

I haven't tried this, so YMMV.