# by default controller search view only in two folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to controller to search for a view in more than two folder (by default controler search in Shared and second folder with its own name ) can we make controller to search in any third folder including above two also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom View Engine

Write a custom view engine and provide all your paths that you want. Then register it in global.asax codebehind in `Application_Start` event handler.

Check this question on SO that will give you all the information you need:
[Can I specify a custom location to "search for views" in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964)