# Search for .cshtml in multiple locations in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When a user comes to my site, there may be a `template=foo` passed in the query string.  This value is being verified and stored in the `Session`.

My file layout looks like this:

```
- Views/
  - Templates/
    - test1/
      - Home
        - Index.cshtml
    - test2/
      - Home
        - List.cshtml
  - Home/
    - Index.cshtml
```

Basically, if a user requests `Index` with `template=test1`, I want to use `Views/Templates/test1/Index.cshtml`.  If they have `template=test2`, I want to use `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` (because `/Views/Templates/test2/Home/Index.cshtml` doesn't exist).  And if they do not pass a template, then it should go directly to `Views/Home`.

I'm new to MVC and .NET in general, so I'm not sure where to start looking.  I'm using MVC3 and Razor for the view engine.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but try to return the view by `return View(string.Concat(Request.QueryString["template"], "/Index"))`

Comment: A more elegant approach would be to derive from the Controller class and override the "View" method, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom RazorViewEngine and setting the `ViewLocationFormats` property. [There's a sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc/909594#909594) that does it by overriding the `WebFormViewEngine`, but using the [`RazorViewEngine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.razorviewengine_properties(v=VS.98).aspx) should work just as well:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
        var viewLocations =  new[] {  
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",  
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",  
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",  
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",  
            "~/AnotherPath/Views/{0}.ascx"
            // etc
        };

        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
        this.ViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify [Scott Hanselman's Mobile Device demo](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) to fit your needs. Instead of checking the user agent or if it's a mobile device, you could put your logic in to check the query string or your Session vars.

Comment: Does this apply for using the Razor view engine?

Comment: Yes. You can use any view engine you'd like. There's an example in there where he uses both Razor and Webforms.