# how does asp.net mvc relate a view to a controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have opened a sample ASP.NET MVC project.

In `HomeController` I have created a method (action) named `MethodA`

```
public ActionResult MethodA()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have right clicked on `MethodA` and created a new view called `MethodA1`

Re-did it and created a new view called `MethodA2`.

1. How is this magical relationship done? I looked for the config to tell the compiler that views `MethodAX` are related to action `MethodA`, but found none.
2. What view will the controller return when `MethodA` is called?

Comment: if you want to know where **MVC** ***looks*** for the `View` just create an action method and forget to add a corresponding `View` ...

Comment: You can also add Custom locations for your Views to be searched from. This means you can add a custom folder structure under `View/FolderName` to keep your Views organized. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc to see how to do it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The convention is that if you don't specify a view name, the corresponding view will be the name of the action. So:

```
public ActionResult MethodA()
{
    return View();
}
```

will render `~/Views/ControllerName/MethodA.cshtml`.

But you could also specify a view name:

```
public ActionResult MethodA()
{
    return View("FooBar");
}
```

and now the `~/Views/ControllerName/FooBar.cshtml` view will be rendered.

Or you could even specify a fully qualified view name which is not inside the views folder of the current controller:

```
public ActionResult MethodA()
{
    return View("~/Views/Foo/Baz.cshtml");
}
```

Now obviously all this assumes Razor as view engine. If you are using WebForms, replace `.cshtml` with `.aspx` or `.ascx` (if you are working with partials).

For example if there is no view it will even tell you where and in what order is looking for views:

[image]

Remember: ASP.NET MVC is all about convention over configuration.

Comment: I still wonder: when I map an action to non-convectional path view where is the new mapping saved?

Comment: It is saved nowhere. Why do you think it must be saved anywhere?

Comment: Because my right click on the action made some unconventional linkage. It should be written somewhere, as it's unconventional

Comment: If you are talking about design time, you cannot unlink. The built-in wizards follow the standard conventions.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I used right click on the action and got view like this http://webmaster.org.il/articles/aspnetmvc-view-details (explanation is in hebrew)

Comment: Remember: ASP.NET MVC is all about convention over configuration. That's what I feel should be kept at the back of the mind always.

Answer (score 11):

The MVC framework use convention over configuration.  The framework calls the ExecuteResult on the ViewResult object (created by the return View();).  The framework by convention then looks in a number of locations to find a view

If you are using areas the framework will look in the following locations for a view.

- /Areas//Views/ControllerName/ViewName.aspx
- /Areas//Views/ControllerName/ViewName.ascx
- /Areas//Views/Shared/ViewName.aspx
- /Areas//Views/Shared/ViewName.ascx
- /Areas//Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml
- /Areas//Views/ControllerName/ViewName.vbhtml
- /Areas//Views/Shared/ViewName.cshtml
- /Areas//Views/Shared/ViewName.vbhtml

Without areas (or if you are using areas and no view has been found) the framework will look at the following locations

- /Views/ControllerName/ViewName.aspx
- /Views/ControllerName/ViewName.ascx
- /Views/Shared/ViewName.aspx
- /Views/Shared/ViewName.ascx
- /Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml
- /Views/ControllerName/ViewName.vbhtml
- /Views/Shared/ViewName.cshtml
- /Views/Shared/ViewName.vbhtml

As soon as the Framework tests a location and finds a file, then the search stops,
and the view that has been found is used to render the response to the client.

There are a number of overriden versions of the View method.  The most common one is to render a specific view, outside of the framework convention, by calling it by name.  For example

```
return View("~/Views/AnotherIndex.cshtml");
```

As an interesting footnote, the framework looks for legacy ASP, C# and VB Razor views (aspx, ascx, cshtml and vbhtml) even though you have a specific view engine.

Comment: Does the performance matter if you use the View override method without a view name Vs. with a view name?

Answer (score 1):

In MVC controller action is not bound to view.
It uses delegate mechanism to pickup the view.

Model Binding(Mapping)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and I just made a couple of tests and figured out.
It doesn't save anywhere.
To understand how it works; just do these steps:

In your controller, right click, Add View
Then enter a different View Name
and Ctrl F5
you will get Server error in application.

For example if you right click , Add View in following Index action method and type "Index2" in View name, you will get the error.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So basically there is a 1-1 matching between action name and View name. And you cannot add view for the same method so there is no need to save in a config file.

Now change the view file name in Visual Studio from Index2.cshtml to Index.cshtml then Ctrl+F5. You should see it is working.