# Using MVC. I'm trying to click a button client side to retrieve a database, so that may also appear on the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a sign in - signout app using MVC C# Visual Studio and I need some assistance.

Whenever I try to click the button to get an `onclick` event, it is suppose to call the `GetList` method and retrieve all of the data in the database where Signout is equal to null in the Visitor column.

It is not hitting the `GetList` method. What do I need to do to move forward?

This is my code:

**Controller**

```
using NameSpaceName.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using ClassLibrary1;
using System.Data;

namespace NameSpaceName.Controllers {
    public class VisitorController : Controller {
        // GET: Visitor
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int id=0) {
            Visitor visitor = new Visitor();
            Entities db = new Entities();
            var employee = db.Employees.ToList();
            return View(visitor);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetList(Visitor visitor) {
            List<String> Visitor = new List<String>();
            using (Entities db = new Entities()) {
                if (visitor.SignOut == null) {
                //
                }
            }
            return View(visitor);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitInfo(FormModel model) {
            return new JsonResult() {
                Data = model,
                MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace NameSpaceName.Web {
    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Submit Info", // Route name
                "visitor/submit-info/", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Visitor", action = "SubmitInfo" } 
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Get Info", // Route name
                "visitor/get-info/", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Visitor", action = "GetInfo" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Visitor", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Partial View _SignInOrSignOut**

```
@using NameSpaceName;
@using ClassLibrary1;

@model Visitor
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetInfo";
}
@{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        OnSuccess = "GetList",
        OnFailure = "NoList",
        Url = "/visitor/get-info/"
    };
}
<ul class="col-xs-12">
    <li class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="button" class="btn-cls SignIn" value="Sign In" name="Sign In" />
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="button" value="Sign Out" class="btn-cls SignOut" name="Sign Out" onclick="@Url.Action("GetInfo", "Visitor")" />
    </li>
</ul>

//jQuery code
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.formSuccess = function (resp) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".signInForm").hide();
            $(".signInBtn").show();
        }, 3000);
    };

    window.formFails = function (resp) {
        debugger;
    };
    window.GetList = function (resp) { alert("Yay"); };
    window.NoList = function (resp) { alert("No"); };
}).on('click', '.btn-cls', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is('.SignIn')) {
        $(".signInBtn").hide();
        $(".signInForm").show();
    } else {
        console.log('SignOut');
    }
});
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-centered signInBtn col-xs-12">
    @Html.Partial("_SignInOrSignOut")
</div>
<div class="col-centered signInForm col-xs-12">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, options, new { @class = "visitor-form" })) {
    <div class="input">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new {
        @class = "firstName required",
        @id = "firstName",
        @placeHolder = "First Name",
        @name = "FirstName",
        @tabIndex = 1
     })
     </div>
     <div class="input">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new {
         @class = "lastName required",
         @id = "lastName",
         @name = "LastName",
         @placeHolder = "Last Name",
         @tabIndex = 2
     })
     </div>
     <div class="input">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company, new {
         @class = "company",
         @id = "company",
         @name = "Company",
         @placeHolder = "Company",
         @tabIndex = 3
     })
     </div>
     <div class="input">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new {
         @class = "emailAddress",
         @id = "emailAddress",
         @name = "EmailAddress",
         @placeHolder = "Email Address",
         @tabIndex = 4
     })
     </div>
     <div class="input">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReasonForVisit, new {
         @class = "reasonForVisit required",
         @id = "reasonForVisit",
         @name = "ReasonForVisit",
         @placeHolder = "Reason For Visit",
         @tabIndex = 5
     })
     </div>
     <div class="input">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeId, Employee.EmployeeDropDown, new { 
                @class="employeeList required",
            })
     </div>
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SignIn)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SignOut)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsEmailed)

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi John, What have you tried yourself? can you go to the url in the browser and see if it is working by setting a breakpoint in your controller

Comment: I did set breakpoints in the controller. It didn't hit there at all. In the view I tried Html.Action, Html.ActionLink, and Ajax.ActionLink nothing is working for me.

Comment: `@Url.Action("GetInfo", "Visitor")` --> `@Url.Action("GetList", "Visitor")` try that please. You dont have an action that is called GetInfo. Please try to go to your url in the browser for example http://localhost:port/visitor/get-info and see whats happening. Also your `RouteConfig` is going to the wrong action

Comment: Jordy I switch everything from GetInfo to GetList and get-info to get-list and I still got nothing.

Comment: Your onclick handler for the Sign Out button won't work because it has invalid JS inside it. You are populating a URL where it's expecting code. Is this the button you expect to be clicked to load the list?

Comment: When/where are you posting your form data back? What are you doing with  those AjaxOptions? Your missing a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

John,
Your Default Map Route should look something like this - notice **"url:"** see if it hits GetList now.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Then look at this explanation on how a your action methods in controller correlate to your views - each controller should have a corresponding view (.cshtml)
[how does asp.net mvc relate a view to a controller action?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896981/3590235)

And there is always a corresponding POST method for a GET with the same name if not; if your aim is to to post your result from GetList() to SubmitInfo()
you have to decorate the method like this

```
     [HttpPost, ActionName("GetList")]
    public ActionResult SubmitInfo(FormModel model) {.....}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have a HomeController though. I only have a VisitorController.  I got a "Server Error in '/' Application." when I changed the default RouteConfig

Comment: Add this portion only url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" see if that works. never mind the Home I copy pasted it.

Comment: I'm confused by the second portion with the HttpPost, and the ActionName. GetList and SubmitInfo are two different methods. SubmitInfo submit the lead in the database. I'm trying to use GetList to retrieve a table back. Are we adding on to that method, because the SubmitInfo method works as is.

Comment: I'm sorry It could be I miss understood you. the 2nd portion is if you are looking to Post - i said that because I didn't see the matching GET. So for the 1st portion -  I was thinking say you get the routing working and land on visitor.cshtml then on the click action **@Html.ActionLink("set ur parms here")** you can hit the GetList which returns what you want on the corresponding view GetList.cshtml