# How to specify the view name in an MVC action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I'm learning Asp MVC. 
I've been doing WPF MVVM programs for two years already, but i also need to learn ASP which is a common language used in web development in my country as far as i know. And i have also knowledge in c# so i think adjusting will not be very hard, but i'm already facing a lot of problems in making my website work. I tried reading about ASP and MVC but i learn by doing things and from my mistake than reading it. So i decided to give it a try.

I created an EMPTY MVC project using Visual Studio Community Edition 2017

I already created the Layout Page and the First Controller and the First View and its totally working fine.

This is the screenshot

[image]

Then i create the second controller. Then the problem comes in.

I created a new controller named `NewPostController` and `ADD View` for it like this

[image]

But it create another folder with the name of the View and inside it is the view it created

[image]

I don't want it to organize that way.

So i dragged the `NewPost.cshtml` into the admin folder. Run the application then i received an error saying

```
The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /Admin/NewPost
```

I did a search for a solution but i can't solve the problem

I tried specifying the view name

```
        public ActionResult NewPost()
        {
            return View("~/Admin/NewPost");
        }
```

Most of the solution i read is specify the View Name. But i can't make it work. What are the things that i missed? Or not understand? Thank you.

Comment: Just use view name like this: `return View("NewPost");`. No need to use full path of cshtml file.

Comment: Why would you change MVC's natural architecture? If you want your `NewPost` action to be in the `Admin` controller folder, then just move your action from the `NewPostController` to the `AdminController`

Comment: Why are you changing the default structure?

Comment: If you want to use non-standard locations for your views I'd recommend you implement a [custom Razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838766/how-do-i-implement-a-custom-razorviewengine-to-find-views-in-non-standard-locati)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i already tried it. but it doesn't work, i tried it like the one posted as answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896950/how-does-asp-net-mvc-relate-a-view-to-a-controller-action

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, That will not work because its in a different controller.

Comment: Your 404 error means that you have not moved the `NewPost` method to the `AdminController` (you need to move both the method and the view)

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke because when i run the VIEW the HTML is like this http://localhost:52304/NewPost/NewPost I don't want it that way. Did i do it wrong?

Comment: You need to move **both** the method and the view file (the `public ActionResult NewPost()` needs to be in `AdminController` and the `NewPost.cshtml` file needs to be in `/Views/Admin/`

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you provide a code snippet for that? Or you mean i need to create a new ActionResult in the AdminController with the name of NewPost

Comment: @classname13 You should move `NewPost` method inside `AdminController` to get `/Admin/NewPost` URL. The `NewPostController` will create `/NewPost/NewPost` instead.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. Stephen and tetsuya. Stackoverflow has lots of people willing to help newbie like me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC have sort of a naming convention where if your controller is named FooController then your views should be keep in a folder name Foo.

Inside this controller you will have your

```
public ActionResult <name of view>
```

name exactly the same as the view for easy referencing.

So when you have a view under the Foo Folder and the name of that cshtml file is Hello
then inside the FooController, you have a

```
public ActionResult Hello(//parameter here){
    //body here
}
```

Hope you understand my explanation.

Also to answer your question. I'm assuming you want the NewPost.cshtml as part of the admin folder. Just add

```
public ActionResult NewPost()
```

to your admin controller and then you can use

```
localhost/admin/NewPost()
```

If i miss anything or any error, please comment hehe answered this in a bit of a rush

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `NewPost` action to your `AdminController` as such:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Here you go
    public ActionResult NewPost()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is default MVC structure if you want both `Dashboard` and `NewPost` views to be in the `Admin` folder