# Failed to return partial view from area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Basically I've just created an Area in my ASP.NET MVC4 application.
It all works great etc, however when I want to return a PartialView as shown below:

```
return PartialView("_ImportSessionsTable", viewModel);
```

(not that the above call is called from the area(admin) view)
I get the following error:

> The partial view '_ImportSessionsTable' was not found or no view
>   engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/ImportSessions/_ImportSessionsTable.aspx
>
> ~/Views/ImportSessions/_ImportSessionsTable.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/_ImportSessionsTable.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/_ImportSessionsTable.ascx
>
> ~/Views/ImportSessions/_ImportSessionsTable.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/ImportSessions/_ImportSessionsTable.vbhtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/_ImportSessionsTable.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/_ImportSessionsTable.vbhtml

The thing is: as far as I can see it isn't looking for the view in the area folder (admin) which is where I have the view stored. How can I get it to look there? Whenever I call `return View();` it works fine so it's only when I specify the view as a string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> How can I get it to look there?

You could specify the full location of the partial to be rendered:

```
return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/ImportSessions/_ImportSessionsTable.cshtml", viewModel);
```

Comment: Well I ended up following your example and it works now by the following path:

~/Areas/Admin/Views/ImportSessions/_ImportSessionsTable.cshtml

I would just assume that it's possible for it to automatically look in the area it's being called in.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider overriding where the viewengine searches for views, but that might be a little extreme for what you're looking for.  See here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc)