# How to use partial view from another project in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have two MVC projects one as a parent project and the other as a child project. The child project adds reference to the parent project. I like to use partial views from the parent project from the child project something like -

`@Html.Partial("_GenericGreeting")` <-- in child project

`_GenericGreeting.cshtml` <-- is in parent project

The child project is the project that starts up. Parent project i mean is like a base/shared project. RazorGenerator has been installed on both projects and each projects can be compiled into single assembles.

When I ran the project, i'm only getting this following error.

> The partial view '_GenericGreeting' was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.

If i copy the partial view and paste it into the child project it's fine but i don't want to duplicate the files.

I have tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc) but no luck but maybe i'm not adding it right.

Comment: Can you show your code on what you tried for implementing class CustomViewEngine and global.asax Application_OnStart() ? It will be different from your linked post for Razor.

Comment: Hi @RaulNoheaGoodness I don't have that code anymore .. I just tried that quickly and didn't work so i deleted it .. But i fixed my problem tho. I created an answer with the fix i have. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really good, but simple solution that can solve your problem. One of overloads `@Html.Partial()` allows you to write full path to your View.

Something like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/View/Shared/_GenericGreeting.cshtml")
```

Comment: Thanks @teo .. this might be a silly question but can you give me an example here if i want to link to different project how do i write the full path in my case?

Comment: @lawphotog if you want to change directory to parent foulder use `..` like this: `@Html.Partial("~/../../OtherProjectFolder/View/Shared/_GenericGreeting.cshtml")`. But make sure that your process that run your site have permissions to this folder.

Answer (score 3):

I accepted teo's answer. He helped me and gave me clue to the problem. But there are few important things to check.

One thing I wasn't aware is the generated cshtml files have properties called `PageVirtualPathAttribute`. One problem i couldn't get the right combination is because i was getting the path wrong.

Another thing to look is this class which is auto generated when you installed RazorGenerator and it is in your App_Start folder.

```
public static class RazorGeneratorMvcStart {
        public static void Start() {
            var engine = new PrecompiledMvcEngine(typeof(RazorGeneratorMvcStart).Assembly) {
                UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal
            };

            ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, engine);

            // StartPage lookups are done by WebPages. 
            VirtualPathFactoryManager.RegisterVirtualPathFactory(engine);
        }
    }
```

However this line has an overload method to define path to your compiled view. My shared project was created by someone else and he put this path in it.

```
var engine = new PrecompiledMvcEngine(typeof(RazorGeneratorMvcStart).Assembly, @"~/Areas/Cart/", null)
```

Once I have those bits checked, I just need to use like the following in my view as teo suggested.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/Cart/Views/Home/_GenericGreeting.cshtml")
```

Comment: Having "Areas" as the first segment is kind of the key.