# How to organise Views into folders in Asp.net visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been forking on a project for a while now and I ended up having a lot of view for different models. I was wandering whether it is possible to organise these views into sub folders. So just to be clear I want to do the following:

Controllers:

```
      MyControllers(Folder)->
         MyFirstController.cs
         MYSubcontroller(Folder)->
             MySubController.cs
```

Views:

```
      MyFirst(Folder)->
         Index.cshtml
         MYSub(Folder)->
             Index.cshtml
```

Comment: Any reason you're using folders for your controllers?

Comment: There are a lot of them and I can find a particular controller more easier if they are split into different categories. I would like to do this for views as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to put views and controllers wherever you want. You can easily customize view paths on App_Start event. See tha answer in this topic: [Can I specify a custom location to "search for views" in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

I would though recommend using the standard project structure and paths. It would makes life easier for other developers that work with your code in the future eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Most basic option would be for your controller routes to specify a view explicitly when returning:

```
return View("PATH-TO-YOUR-VIEW");
```

But I'm not a fan of this approach as you lose the nice built in MVC conventions.

By default, the Razor View Engine will use the following conventions when locating views:

```
~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml
~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml
```

1. The view name
2. The controller name

With this in mind, if you have a controller named `MySubController` with the default `Index` action, you would normally have a view file:

```
~/Views/MySub/Index.cshtml
```