# Can we recursively search sub folders when looking for a view in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewengine

I know that I can can add search locations to a `View Engine` as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc).

I was just wondering is there any way to tell the view engine to then recursively search sub folders without having to specify the entire path?

E.g. if I had a folder structure like /Shared/Partials/Subfolder/Subfolders/MyView

Could I add a search locations like /Shared/Partials/* or similar?

I can't find anything so I don't think it is possible but thought I may as well ask here.

Thanks

Comment: You could create the array by using system.filesystem to get all the folders you need

Answer (score 1):

What if you use something like this in your viewengine array?

```
Directory.GetDirectories("c:/somepath/Shared/Partials");
```

The above returns an array of strings.

So you could write the following:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
        var viewLocations =  Directory.GetDirectories("c:/somepath/Shared/Partials");

        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
        this.ViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
    }
}
```

And also register your new engine:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
}
```