# Adding a search location in ASP.NET Core's ViewEngineExpander

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've read several tutorials that explain how to *replace* the default path to the views folder in the case that the views folder needs to be moved. However, I've been trying to figure out how to *add* a path that is searched by the view engine.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class BetterViewEngine : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        return viewLocations.Select(s => s.Add("")); //Formerly s.Replace("oldPath", "newPath" but I wish to add
    }
}
```

And in my *Startup.cs*

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new BetterViewEngine());
        });
```

Comment: You want to change default location for views?

Comment: See this post: [Can I specify a custom location to “search for views” in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change default behavior for searching the views, try this:

```
public class BetterViewEngine : IViewLocationExpander
{
   public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
   {
        context.Values["customviewlocation"] = nameof(BetterViewEngine);
   }

   public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(
        ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
   {
        return new[]
        {
             "/folderName/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
             "/folderName/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
   }
}
```

But if you just want to rename one of the folders try this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(
      ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
{

      // Swap /Shared/ for /_Shared/
      return viewLocations.Select(f => f.Replace("/Shared/", "/_Shared/"));

}
```

Comment: I wasn't looking to change the default location. I just needed the engine to search one more place other than the default. In either case, your example would work. Thanks

Comment: How can i pass additional information to the view path? For example i want to have the following path: "/folderName/{1}/{0}.{2}.cshtml" where {2} is a placeholder for the current culture (e.g. en-US)? My problem is that i want to return a "localized" view if it does exists (/folderName/Home/Index.en-US.cshtml) or return default view (/folderName/Home/Index.cshtml) otherwise. Is there any simple solution for this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just expanding on Sirwan's answer since it took me a minute to figure out what I needed to do after reading the first part of his answer:

```
public class ViewLocationRemapper : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "/Views/" + context.Values["admin"] + "/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
        };
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        context.Values["admin"] = "AdminViews";
    }
}
```