# CS1061 partial view not loaded in nopcommerce plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm developing nopcommerce plugin and calling partial view in master page. but loaded  show this error:

> CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Patial' and no extension method 'Patial' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: As per below comments, it search on location where it can not find the view called "vendorProfile" so put that view to `~/Themes/twigoh/Views/Dashboard/`

Comment: set the path of view  return PartialView("~/Plugins/Twigoh.Sellers/Views/Dashboard/vendorProfile.cshtml", model);
When i direct hit controller and action it works fine. but when loaded in master view its show error.

Comment: Why do you want to load that on master view?

Comment: because this vendorProfile where show only avater and name of vendor

Comment: now CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @{Html.RenderPartial("vendorProfile");}

Comment: can we use @ sign before Html code

Comment: Yes, got it, *but when loaded in master view its show error* because it's try to find in shared folder but not get that view and shows an error. rather than call `@Html.Partial` use  `@Html.RenderAction` or else copy that view to shared folder.

Comment: yep its error was same on @html.Raw(test);

Comment: Hope you've solved the issue.

Comment: no same  CS0103: The name 'test' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Did you tried  *Yes, got it, but when loaded in master view its show error because it's try to find in shared folder but not get that view and shows an error. rather than call Html.Partial use Html.RenderAction or else copy that view to shared folder.*

Comment: partial view not running.. their is issue on nopcommerce new version

Comment: yes your answer was correct..  partial view running fine in my mvc app. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment you got an error of:

> The partial view 'vendorProfile' was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were

Which means it searched on location where it can not find the view called "vendorProfile" so put that view to `~/Themes/twigoh/Views/Dashboard/` or you can return partial view from your plugin like:

```
PartialView("~/Plugins/Twigoh.Sellers/Views/Dashboard/vendor‌​Profile.cshtml", model);
```

but *when loaded in master view its show an error* because it's try to find in shared folder but not get that view. So,rather than call `@Html.Partial` use `@Html.RenderAction` or else copy that view to shared folder.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo.  You're using `@Html.Patial("myview")` instead of `@Html.Partial("myview")`

Comment: Yes, this could be the issue.

Comment: and also exception throw this An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Did you copy and paste your error or type it yourself?  It has the term `'Patial'` twice

Comment: also view show this The partial view 'vendorProfile' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: The partial view 'vendorProfile' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Themes/twigoh/Views/Dashboard/vendorProfile.cshtml
~/Themes/twigoh/Views/Shared/vendorProfile.cshtml
~/Views/Dashboard/vendorProfile.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/vendorProfile.cshtml
~/Administration/Views/Dashboard/vendorProfile.cshtml
~/Administration/Views/Shared/vendorProfile.cshtml

Comment: Is vendorProfile.cshtml located at any of those locations?  If not, you should put it in one of those locations, or you can try following this question to specify a custom location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc