# The term for the folder that View is in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, terminology

Actions reside in controllers, That makes it easy to say Action X in Controller Y.

Views have a similarity to action, the name of the folder that they are in must match the name of controller, Do we say View X for Controller Folder Y ? or is there another term used for the folder that contains all the view for a Controller?

Comment: The name of the folder that they are in does **not** need to match the name of controller - that's just a convention and means you no not need to explicitly declare the path to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Huh? how do we return a view from a different folder? Beside convention I thought it is a restriction of how mvc works, can't return a view from a different folder other than the one matching the controller name.

Comment: Of course you can. You can specify the full path to the view, or you can configure the view engine to search for view files in any folder you want (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc) for an example).

Comment: I'd also mention that the Default ViewEngine looks for a view in multiple folders already, so which folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that important how you call the folder?

There is no special name for that folder. And really, folder with views for the controller is a vague term - some views can have partial views that sit in `Shared` folder. And you can also implement your own `ViewEngine` with your own convention. Or even supply view files from a database.

So to answer your question - there is no special term.