# ASP.NET MVC Set Views folder on controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If you have created a controller like:

```
public class ProjectLoginController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// GET: /login
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It will search for the login view in the `ProjectLogin` or the `Shared` folder.

Is it possible to tell MVC for this controller to search in the views folder `Account` under `Views`instead of doing:

```
return View("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml");
```

or:

```
return View("../Account/Login");
```

Comment: You can do like this, `return View("../Account/Login", yourModel );`

Comment: But is there no attribute you can set with the default views folder to search in for this particular controller?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Mivaweb I have the same problem. I need to do this for a single controller. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MartinD. seems a long time ago, but I remember that the link of Krishna was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RedirectToAction() method for this. For example,

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account");
```

Or-else, do like this,

```
return View("../Account/Login");
```

Hoe it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by following ways:

```
return View("../Account/Login");
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account");
```