# Need to "extend" RazorView to accept physical path to layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Has anyone had any success loading `_Layout.cshtml` from a *physical path* before?

Problem: At present, MVC throws an error if you attempt to pass something like `C:\dedicated\path\to\layouts\_Layout.cshtml` to the `Layout` property in `_ViewStart.cshtml` due to the executing page hierarchy ("virtual path expected").

Been doing a bit of research and experimentation with this already and have a couple different "hacks" available as workarounds including deriving from `RazorView` through replacing `ExecutePageHierarchy` altogether with RunCompile from the RazorEngine NuGet package (probably best bet).

Curious if anyone has come up with a concrete solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to write your own custom view engine for that, which will search in the specific path.

Comment: That's one of the workarounds I've looked into, hence wanting to "extend" RazorViewEngine. I really don't want to *replace* Razor.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't be replacing the default RazorViewEngine, you can have multiple view engines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I specify a custom location to "search for views" in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: That's not quite the same thing. Here I want to continue using Razor for rendering but add support for rendering it in a layout loaded from a physical location (currently unsupported). At a bare minimum, I would have to replicate `WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy` and everything it does just to get at `PopContext` calling `NormalizeLayoutPagePath` and further down the stack until `System.Web.Util.UrlPath.CheckValidVirtualPath` is called and finally throws the error. Still working out this direction though as it may be the closest workaround.

Comment: @NightOwl888 My reply was to 12seconds but regardless, if you try passing a *physical path* you'll get an exception per my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an initial implementation and only supports static HTML files (no Razor rendering), but it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.WebPages;

namespace Enterprise.InHouse.Shared.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Primitive HTML template wrapper for RazorView where physical layout paths are unsupported.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Derived from https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorView.cs
    /// </remarks>
    public class PhysicalPathView : RazorView
    {
        #region Proof of Concept (TODO: Refactor)

        public static readonly string HeaderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhysicalPathView.HeaderPath"];
        public static readonly string FooterPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhysicalPathView.FooterPath"];

        // TODO: Optimize
        private static void StaticTemplateWrap(Action body, TextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write(File.ReadAllText(HeaderPath));
            body();
            writer.Write(File.ReadAllText(FooterPath));
        }

        #endregion

        #region RazorView

        public PhysicalPathView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string layoutPath, bool runViewStartPages, IEnumerable<string> viewStartFileExtensions)
            : this(controllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, runViewStartPages, viewStartFileExtensions, null)
        {
        }

        public PhysicalPathView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string layoutPath, bool runViewStartPages, IEnumerable<string> viewStartFileExtensions, IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)
            : base(controllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, runViewStartPages, viewStartFileExtensions, viewPageActivator)
        {
            //LayoutPath = layoutPath ?? string.Empty; // ! Read-only
            //RunViewStartPages = runViewStartPages; // ! Read-only
            //StartPageLookup = StartPage.GetStartPage; // ! Non-existent
            //ViewStartFileExtensions = viewStartFileExtensions ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>(); // ! Read-only
        }

        protected override void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, object instance)
        {
            if (writer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
            }

            WebViewPage webViewPage = instance as WebViewPage;
            if (webViewPage == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Wrong view base: {0}", ViewPath));
                    //String.Format(
                    //    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    //    MvcResources.CshtmlView_WrongViewBase, // ! Non-existent
                    //    ViewPath));
            }

            // An overriden master layout might have been specified when the ViewActionResult got returned.
            // We need to hold on to it so that we can set it on the inner page once it has executed.
            //webViewPage.OverridenLayoutPath = LayoutPath; // ! Non-existent
            webViewPage.VirtualPath = ViewPath;
            webViewPage.ViewContext = viewContext;
            webViewPage.ViewData = viewContext.ViewData;

            webViewPage.InitHelpers();

            // ! Non-existent
            //if (VirtualPathFactory != null)
            //{
            //    webViewPage.VirtualPathFactory = VirtualPathFactory;
            //}

            // ! Non-existent
            //if (DisplayModeProvider != null)
            //{
            //    webViewPage.DisplayModeProvider = DisplayModeProvider;
            //}

            WebPageRenderingBase startPage = null;

            // ! Non-existent
            //if (RunViewStartPages)
            //{
            //    startPage = StartPageLookup(webViewPage, RazorViewEngine.ViewStartFileName, ViewStartFileExtensions);
            //}

            StaticTemplateWrap(() =>
            {
                webViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(new WebPageContext(context: viewContext.HttpContext, page: null, model: null), writer, startPage);
            }, writer);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Derive a new view engine class from `RazorViewEngine`, override its `CreateView` to return an instance of this class, and register in **Global.asax**.

I'll update this answer with a more complete solution as it becomes available.

---

Update (1/17/18) - The above implementation has been cleaned up and is provided below. It still only renders static HTML, which is fine for now, but also exposes a custom `RenderViewWrapper` helper in the `LayoutWrapperViewEngine` class which you can implement/refactor any way you want.

**LayoutWrapperView.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Enterprise.Apps.Shared.Web
{
    public class LayoutWrapperView : RazorView
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Outer lambda for caller to wrap inner lambda.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Action<Action, TextWriter> RenderViewWrapper;

        public LayoutWrapperView(Action<Action, TextWriter> renderViewWrapper, ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string layoutPath, bool runViewStartPages, IEnumerable<string> viewStartFileExtensions)
            : this(renderViewWrapper, controllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, runViewStartPages, viewStartFileExtensions, null) { }

        public LayoutWrapperView(Action<Action, TextWriter> renderViewWrapper, ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string layoutPath, bool runViewStartPages, IEnumerable<string> viewStartFileExtensions, IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)
            : base(controllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, runViewStartPages, viewStartFileExtensions, viewPageActivator)
        {
            RenderViewWrapper = renderViewWrapper;
        }

        protected override void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, object instance)
        {
            if (RenderViewWrapper != null)
            {
                RenderViewWrapper(() =>
                {
                    base.RenderView(viewContext, writer, instance);
                }, writer);
            } else
            {
                base.RenderView(viewContext, writer, instance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LayoutWrapperViewEngine.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Enterprise.Apps.Shared.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom ViewEngine extension for RazorViewEngine designed to support physical paths (i.e. C:\Inetpub\shared\layouts -> \\server\share\layouts)
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// In .NET 4.5.2, physical paths are not supported in _ViewStart.cshtml due to Server.MapPath validation (only virtual paths allowed).
    /// This class provides an alternate ViewEngine to support shared layouts via physical paths as in the following:
    /// 
    /// net use \\server\share\layouts
    /// mklink /d C:\Inetpub\shared\layouts \\server\share\layouts
    /// </remarks>
    public class LayoutWrapperViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public static readonly string HeaderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LayoutView.HeaderPath"];
        public static readonly string FooterPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LayoutView.FooterPath"];

        protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
        {
            return new LayoutWrapperView(RenderViewWrapper, controllerContext, viewPath,
                layoutPath: masterPath, runViewStartPages: true, viewStartFileExtensions: FileExtensions, viewPageActivator: ViewPageActivator);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes static header/footer to response buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="body"></param>
        /// <param name="responseBuffer"></param>
        private static void RenderViewWrapper(Action body, TextWriter responseBuffer)
        {
            try
            {
                responseBuffer.Write(File.ReadAllText(HeaderPath));
            } catch (Exception)
            {
                // TODO: Implement exception handling
            }

            body();

            try
            {
                responseBuffer.Write(File.ReadAllText(FooterPath));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // TODO: Implement exception handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Enterprise.Apps.Shared.Web;

namespace Enterprise.Apps.Web
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

            // Use only LayoutWrapperViewEngine
            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new LayoutWrapperViewEngine());

            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LayoutView.HeaderPath" value="C:\Inetpub\shared\layouts\header.html" />
    <add key="LayoutView.FooterPath" value="C:\Inetpub\shared\layouts\footer.html" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```