# How to override RazorViewEngine when searching for EditorTemplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine, mvc-editor-templates

It seems like that the default `RazorViewEngine` in the asp.net mvc 5 framework, only look for `EditorTemplate` in a folder named `EditorTemplate` inside the `Shared` folder. I am okay with that convention, the only thing I would like to add it search for `EditorTemplate` in the `Shared/EditorTemplates` and any folder inside if I place my EditorTemplate in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SomeNewFolder` it would still find it.

How can I extend the `RazorViewEngine` to tell razor to recursively look for any folder inside the `EditorTemplates` folder when searching for `EditorTemplate`?

Comment: You want it to search whatever folder structure you create or provide the folders it has to search?

Comment: Basically look inside the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and any other folder inside of it

Comment: I would strongly recommend against that. For a start the view engine system is designed to use a predefined list, even though you could fudge it to be dynamic. However the main reason is that this could affect your site performance as it needs to search the folder structure.

Comment: I would agree if there were lots of folders. The idea is to allow me to have couple sub folder to separate my editor templates. Having many editor templates in one folder is messy.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how many folders, the act of scanning in the first place is expensive. If you only have a couple of folders though, why not just add them to the list?

Comment: Note the the view engine also searches in `/Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates/` by default

Comment: @DavidG that’s not a bad idea. Can you please guid me on how to add a folder called DefaultTypes?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for that tip. That may come in handy if the editor is explicitly used by one controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc